# Stream video from Android to computer

Tags: android, image, video-streaming

I am looking for a way to stream video from the android camera to a computer; I'll be need to run some heavy image processing algorithms on the computers end real time to extract data from the images/video.

Being new to Android, I'm trying to figure out the best way to transfer the images real time so that I can process the video stream on the computer. If there are good methods anyone recommends for this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) a [ParcelFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#fromDatagramSocket%28java.net.DatagramSocket%29) to a [DatagramSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html).

Comment: Do you know how to deal with the packet on the receiving end?